# Stored procedure or CTE to select data between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This code is not working :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReportBetweenTwoDates 
    @DateOne DateTime,
    @DateTwo DateTime
AS
BEGIN
;
    SELECT 
        VisitorID, VisitorName, VisitorAddress, 
        ContactNumber, Department, ToMeet, InTime,
        Purpose, OutTime 
    FROM 
        tbl_visitor
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(varchar(20), InTime, 110) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(20), @DateOne, 110) AND CONVERT(varchar(20), @DateTwo, 110)
END
```

Comment: Would you please be more precise ?

Comment: Be more specific, post what you are trying to achieve and if you've got any error message edit the question and include error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are `DATETIME`, and I sure hope your `InTime` column in the table is a `DATETIME`, too, then you could easily just use:

```
WHERE 
    InTime BETWEEN @DateOne AND @DateTwo
```

or if you need to get rid of the time portion, use the `DATE` datatype:

```
WHERE 
    CAST(InTime AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@DateOne AS DATE) AND CAST(@DateTwo AS DATE)
```

Stop converting dates to string all the time just for comparison! This is totally pointless and usually leads to problems. Do it the **right way** - use the `DATETIME` and/or `DATE` datatypes natively!